# Converting a dictionary to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary record randomly generated looking like this (could have potentially more record)

```
{'Device_ID': 4, 'Temp1': 58.685912388818124, 'Temp2': 74.55450362769994, 'Temp3': 29.342956194409062, 'Temp_Ambient': 22.89076035200238, 'Time': 19}
{'Device_ID': 6, 'Temp1': 48.75315131444877, 'Temp2': 63.62846644589365, 'Temp3': 24.376575657224386, 'Temp_Ambient': 22.540969718435385, 'Time': 15}
```

I would like the keys: Device ID, Temp1, Temp2, Temp3, Time, Temp_Ambient to be columns of the dataframe

when i try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([record], columns=record.keys())
```

it only shows one row of data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's a list of dicts:

```
lod = [{'Device_ID': 4, 'Temp1': 58.685912388818124, 'Temp2': 74.55450362769994, 'Temp3': 29.342956194409062, 'Temp_Ambient': 22.89076035200238, 'Time': 19},
{'Device_ID': 6, 'Temp1': 48.75315131444877, 'Temp2': 63.62846644589365, 'Temp3': 24.376575657224386, 'Temp_Ambient': 22.540969718435385, 'Time': 15}]
df = pd.DataFrame(lod)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Device_ID      Temp1      Temp2      Temp3  Temp_Ambient  Time
0          4  58.685912  74.554504  29.342956      22.89076    19
1          6  48.753151  63.628466  24.376576      22.54097    15
```